# How to redirect in .htacces &Itemid=x to &Itemid=Y

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, joomla2.5, http-status-code-301

Hello I have this issue

I cant redirect this
index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=435
To this
index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=565

catid=8 is a variable i need redirect all the catid= values

Im only need to chanche &Itemid=435 to &Itemid=565

I have this code

```
   RewriteEngine on
    RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)\&Itemid=435$ $1&Itemid=565
```

I dont know what is wrong
I need all the urls anything&Itemid=435 goes to sameanything&Itemid=565

Comment: Another option is do this

From: myurl/index.php/variable

To: myurl/index.php/clasificados/variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative**

Add below `PHP Code` at the top of `index.php` or `configuration.php` of Joomla!

It checks for numerical `catid` & `Itemid` requests & if `Itemid=435` It will redirect URL with `catid` & new `Itemid`. Feel free to modify code according to your need!

```
if(isset($_GET['catid']) && is_numeric($_GET['catid']) && isset($_GET['Itemid']) && is_numeric($_GET['Itemid']))        
if($_GET['Itemid'] == 435)
{
    $catid    = $_GET['catid'];
    $location = "/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=$catid&Itemid=565";
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: '. $location);
}
```

---

**Answer - 2**

I assumed that you wants is to redirect `URI-1` to `URI-2`.

1. index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=**435**
2. index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=**565**

Below `mod_rewrite` will let you redirect `specific URI` to other `specific URI`. 
Just add below rules in `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=435$
 RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=565 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

**Answer - 3**

Use below in your `.htaccess`, if you want to handle requests with`'/index.php'` and `'/'`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=435$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=8&Itemid=565 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**NOTE: Do not use both code in single `.htaccess` file.**

Comment: Thank Mayur But is not the correct code

I have many &catid=x when x is a number

Comment: You can use `PHP` code to perform such `301 redirection`, I have added `sample code` which may lead you to your desired result.